# Calculating AER with an unknown.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this word problem that I can't figure out. It's pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it right no matter what I try.

> If, instead, the \$4000 was invested in a 3-year savings bond which also amounted to $4607.19 on maturity, calculate the AER(annual equivalent rate) for the savings bond to one decimal place.

Here's one of my approaches:

$4000(1+x)^3 = 4607.19$

$4000(1+x^3) = 4607.19$

$4000 + 4000x^3 = 4607.19$

$4000x^3 = 607.19$

$4000x = 
\sqrt[3]{607.19}$

$4000x = 8.467883416$

$x = 0.00211697085$

$100x = 0.2116970854$

---

---

Here's another:

$4607.19 = 4000(1+\frac{x}{100})^3$

$\sqrt[3]{4607.19} = 4000(1+\frac{x}{100})$

$2.870314701 = 4000 + \frac{4000x}{100}$

$287.0314701 = 400000 + 4000x$ Well, doesn't work out from here on out.

Obviously, both of these are wrong, not to mention that each gives a different answer. The right answer is 4.8%, but I can't seem to come to it.

Comment: I think you are missing the first half of the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
$$4000x^3 = 4607.19$$
$$x^3=\frac{4607.19}{4000}$$
$$x=\sqrt[3]\frac{4607.19}{4000}$$
$$x=1.048 \text{ to 4 significant figures.}$$
Therefore, the AER is $4.8\%$

---

A flaw in the first method is:

$$(1+x)^3 \neq (1+x^3)$$
rather
$$(1+x)^3 = x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$

---

Another flaw in the first method is that 
$$4000x^3=607.19$$
but
$$4000x \neq \sqrt[3]{607.19}$$
rather
$$\sqrt[3]{4000} \times \sqrt[3]{x^3} = \sqrt[3]{607.19}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4000}x = \sqrt[3]{607.19}$$